# Why I can't print the result?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to make a print but the result is always 0.0 in 3 spaces that I have, I've been working in this but I can't find the reason, the first problem that I had, was that I was creating a new variable called perimetro and superficie, so I've tried using the variable that I've created in Figura Class but the problem is still there

```
    package pruebas;
    import figuras.*;

    public class Pruebas {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Circulo figura1 = new Circulo(1.0f);

        figura1.calculaPerimetro();
        figura1.calculaSuperficie();

        System.out.println(figura1.toString());

    }    
}

package figuras;
public abstract class Figura {    
    protected String tipo;
    protected static int contador = 0;
    protected int numSerie;
    protected float perimetro;
    protected float superficie;

    public Figura (String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;

    Figura.contador++;
    numSerie = Figura.contador;
    }

    public abstract float calculaPerimetro();
    public abstract float calculaSuperficie();

    public String toSttring() {
    return this.tipo + ", " + numSerie;    
    }

}

package figuras;

public class Circulo extends Figura{

    private float radio;

    public Circulo (float radio) {

    super("Circulo");
    radio = this.radio;

    }

    @Override
    public float calculaPerimetro() {

    perimetro = (float) (2 * Math.PI * radio);
    return perimetro;

    }

    @Override
    public float calculaSuperficie() {

    superficie = (float) (Math.PI * radio * radio);
    return superficie;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toSttring() + ", " + radio + ", " + perimetro + ", "+ superficie;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not

```
radio = this.radio;
```

but

```
this.radio = radio;
```

Comment: Also a problem in overridden `toString` as he has `toSttring`

Comment: @CalvinP.: not a problem if he doesn't try to call it explicitly from the abstract super class, since he names it correctly in the child class.

Comment: True, I was just pointing out the typo. +1 btw

Comment: @CalvinP.: thanks, but the 1+ will give me no rep. The basic error was so trivial, a typo really, that I couldn't see gaining rep for answering this and made my answer a community wiki.

Comment: @HovercraftFullofEels Thanks, it worked, you were really helpful!!!